# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the jquery-datatables-rails gem to display information using json. Since adding the required code for filtering to work it is failing to display anything with the above error.

I've added the full method below but this is the offending line as raised in the stack trace

```
render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
```

Initialize method

```
  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end
```

Index method

```
  def index
    @sbcons = Subcontractor.scoped
    if filters = params[:filter]
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(sbcon_type: filters[:type]) unless filters[:type].blank?
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(cscs_card: filters[:cscs]) unless filters[:cscs].blank?
      @sbcons = @sbcons.where(approved_status: filters[:approved]) unless filters[:approved].blank?
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
      end
    end
  end
```

Stack trace

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  app/datatables/subcontractors_datatable.rb:4:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:35:in `new'
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  app/controllers/subcontractors_controller.rb:32:in `index'
```

Comment: The error is coming from the initialize in the SubcontractorsModel, not from render json: Check your initialize.

Comment: I've added the initialize method if you could shed any light on it

Comment: it definitely shows only one arg is expected

Comment: Should I add @sbcons to the initialize method as well?

Comment: well, you should know what is expected from your classes!

Comment: @apneadiving are you a teacher of RoR?

Comment: @Abram I could teach Rails better than Tango. Always good to make people think twice.

Comment: @apneadiving Nice one. By the way gmaps4rails4life! Heheh

Comment: @Abram :) It recalls me I actually have much work to do on this... ;)

Comment: Get to work! We love the gem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to correct this type the following:

```
render json: SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)
```

Initialize method

```
  def initialize(view, sbcons)
    @view = view
    @sbcons = sbcons
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read your error message you'll see that the error message is coming from the initialize method on the datatable.

Your datatable initialize is defined as `def initialize(view)`

ergo it takes one parameter: `view`. You're passing in two arguments:

`SubcontractorsDatatable.new(view_context, @sbcons)`

Thereby you are passing 2 args into a method that expects 1 and getting your error.